# Error converting Excel range to Jpeg and inserting into Outlook

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010, outlook-2010

I have code to convert a range in Excel 2010 to a Jpeg and insert that into Outlook 2010.  The code converts the range to a chart and then creates the Jpeg.  The Jpeg will sometimes get corrupted and show the chart in the background behind the range I am attempting to show.  Here is an example:

[image: Jpeg Error]

Here is my code for this:

```
Sub Mail_AS_Pic()

Dim TempFilePath As String
Dim OutApp As Outlook.Application
Dim OutMail As Outlook.MailItem

On Error Resume Next

Kill TempFilePath & "Quota.jpg"

Dim sh As Worksheet
Set sh = Sheets("Strategic")

    'Create a new Microsoft Outlook session
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("outlook.application")
    'create a new message
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

    With OutMail
        .SentOnBehalfOfName = "Me@Me.Com"
        .Display
        .Subject = "Strategic Sales"
        .To = "Me@Me.Com"
        Call createJpg("Strategic", "A1:F11", "Quota")
        'This runs the macro below and creates the jpeg
        TempFilePath = Environ$("temp") & "\"
        .Attachments.Add TempFilePath & "Quota.jpg", olByValue, 0
        'we attached the embedded image with a Position at 0 (makes the attachment hidden)
        '.Attachments.Add 
        'Then we add an html <img src=''> link to this image
        'Note than you can customize width and height - not mandatory

        '<br><br> is a return or line space
        .HTMLBody = "<br>" _
            & "Attached please find the Strategic Sales for the month." _
            & "<br><br>" _
            & "Please reach out to me with any questions." _
            & "<br><br>" _
            & "<img src='cid:Quota.jpg'" & "width=width height=heigth><br><br>" _
            & "<br><br>" _
            & "Thank you," _
            & .HTMLBody

        .Display
        '.Send
    End With

Kill TempFilePath & "Quota.jpg"

Set sh = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing
Set OutMail = Nothing


End Sub

Sub createJpg(Namesheet As String, nameRange As String, nameFile As String)
ThisWorkbook.Activate
Worksheets(Namesheet).Activate
Set Plage = Nothing
Set Plage = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Namesheet).Range(nameRange)
Plage.CopyPicture
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Namesheet).ChartObjects.Add(Plage.Left, Plage.Top, Plage.width, Plage.height)
    .Activate
    .Chart.Paste
    .Chart.Export Environ$("temp") & "\" & nameFile & ".jpg", "JPG"
End With
    Worksheets(Namesheet).ChartObjects(Worksheets(Namesheet).ChartObjects.Count).Delete

Set Plage = Nothing

End Sub
```

I am using this code in several Workbook, one of which creates a Jpeg for two separate ranges.  One of the conversions works every time, the other creates and error every time.  Both are converting data from a Pivot table.

I've been trying to solve this for some time with no luck.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'd suggest adding `.Chart.ChartArea.Clear` before you paste the picture in.

Comment: Where would I place this in the code?

Comment: Just before `.Chart.Paste`

Comment: Clearing the chart did not work, but I finally discovered the root issue.  In both cases where the Jpeg would show the chart in the background I was tying to convert a range with two separate Pivot Tables.  If the range I am selecting only has one pivot table, it will work every time.  When I try to include two pivot tables it will not work.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is created when trying to convert more than one table into a picture.  My solution was to create each table as its own Jpeg, and insert each jpeg into the Email.